# Solve hyperbolic problem

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, hyperbolic-functions

This would be classed as homework (although I am not a student, I'm going through an old textbook of mine).

The question is in two parts:

1. Express $\sinh(x+iy)$ in the form $u+iv$, where $x,y,u,v$ are real, and show that 
   $|\sinh(x+iy)|^{2} = \frac{1}{2}(\cosh(2x) - \cos(2y))$
2. if $\sinh(x+iy) = e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}$ prove either

$x = \ln(\frac{\sqrt 6  + \sqrt 2}{2}), y= 2n\pi + \pi/4$

or

$x = \ln(\frac{\sqrt 6  - \sqrt 2}{2}), y= 2n\pi + 3\pi/4$

where $n$ is an integer.

I can solve part 1. 
$\sinh(x+iy) = \cos(y)\sinh(x)+ i\sin(y)\cosh(x)$, and by each of the summands, expanding the hyperbolic parts and rearranging I can prove the equality.

However, I cannot prove part 2. It's becoming quite annoying. I would assume part 1 should be used to prove part 2, but cannot find a way to use it.

If $ e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}$ is expressed in cartesian coords, it is $1/2 + i\sqrt 3/2$.

So

$\cos(y)\sinh(x) = 1/2$, and
$\sin(y)\cosh(x) = \sqrt 3 /2$.

I tried expanding the hyperbolics, and substituting $u=e^{x}$, and end up with two very ugly quadratics, that seem to get me noewhere.